# Zoom suppresses all audio during zoom meeting

Tags: zoom-meeting

Since a couple months ago, I've noticed that, during zoom meeting, no audio is coming through from Chrome and media player despite audio is working fine in zoom. To put in a another way, I can't secretly watch YouTube during zoom class. I've tried to google the problem, but come up with nothing.

In the picture attached, the volume mixer shows that chrome is playing YouTube, but no sound is coming through my headphone (only audio from zoom meeting). Only when I leave zoom meeting does sound from Chrome returns (same goes with media player as well).

Is there any option that I overlook? I'm sorry if the question is a bit crude, and please don't judge. Online classes are boring.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the volume icon in the notification area. Choose *Sounds* from the menu. Change tab to *Communications*. You have *Mute all other sounds* selected. Change it to a different option that suits your needs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did as you as, and reboot the laptop. However the same issue persists. Any idea?